# How to fix 'string too long' error in xdev C++ api when connect to MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm using MySQL Connector/C++  8.0.15 to connect MySQL Database ,When I run the example in Visual Studio 2017,it failed with an error "string too long".

My operating system Windows 10 and I use Visual Studio 2017,I just use X DevAPI for C++.

```
void test_XdevCPlus_demo()
{
    std::string usr = "root";
    std::string pwd = "1030";
    // Connect to MySQL Server on a network machine
    try
    {
        Session mySession(
            SessionOption::USER, usr,
            SessionOption::PWD, pwd,
            SessionOption::HOST, "localhost",
            SessionOption::PORT, 33060,
            SessionOption::DB, "test",
            SessionOption::SSL_MODE, SSLMode::DISABLED
        );

        Schema myDb = mySession.getSchema("test");
    }
    catch (mysqlx::Error::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I run the example, I got 
Creating session on localhost, port 33060 ... 
STD EXCEPTION: string too long 
The exception happens at Impl::from_utf8(*this, utf8) where utf8="root". 
// TODO: make utf8 conversions explicit

```
string(const char *other)
    {
        if (!other)
            return;
        std::string utf8(other);
        -- > Impl::from_utf8(*this, utf8);
    }


    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        cout << "STD EXCEPTION: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
```

Would you please help?

Comment: What happens if you use `usr.c_str()` and `pwd.c_str()` in you `mySession` parameter list?

Comment: I tried but it failed with same exception 'string too long'.

Comment: I have the same issue. Glad I came across this. Will keep checking.

Answer (score 0):

I runned into similar problem. I was getting a string conversion exception using Visual Studio 17. I solved the issue with the following steps:

1. I configure the "Character set" in "configuration properties -> Advance" to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set".
2. I double checked that I'm building in x64 and release mode. Looks like the biniaries are build only in release mode.

That fixed the issue for me. hopefully helps.